# How to set map size in Google Maps API v3?

Tags: google-maps

I create a map in a div with 'display: none'. With google maps v2 I could set the 'size' parameter to the size of the div once shown, but this 'size' option disappeared in v3 of the API.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resize a Google Map with JavaScript after it has loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743214/how-do-i-resize-a-google-map-with-javascript-after-it-has-loaded)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Change the size of the div using any method you want, and then call `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')`. A related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782632/google-map-display-from-a-hidden-area/3782805#3782805).

Comment: I will add it to Gist