# google maps is not centered in ajax loaded page

Tags: google-maps

In a webapp I´m loading a page (googlemap.asp with the map) with ajax.

I´m loading the "googlemap.asp" in a div with jquery.load and it is displaying the center in the top left corner. It is not rendering the map correctly when I load it this way.

But if I just load the "googlemap.asp" directly in the browser(without ajax) then it displays right, so I guess I have to refreash it somehow when I load it with ajax?

This is what I have:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:600px; width:320px;" ></div>

window.onload=googleMaploadScript();
var address1 = document.getElementById('address').value;

function googleMaploadScript() {
    var script =document.createElement("script");
    script.type="text/javascript";
    script.src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);  
    }




var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(57.109577,12.286513),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);  
  codeAddress(address1);

}

function codeAddress(address) {
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location,
      });    
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });

}
```

Since I load the page with .load is is hidden until you navigate to the div, then it becomes visible, maybe that´s the problem?
I guess I load it in the wrong order somehow, and thats why it is not rendering right, or could it be that the div is not visible at start?

Any input appreciated, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google map display from a hidden area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782632/google-map-display-from-a-hidden-area)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem before

don't use

```
 geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {.....
```

when loading a page with ajax, "geocoder.geocode..." can't return correct geometry.location.
I don't why

but when I try to change my code, map is working

my code like

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+youraddress+"&sensor=false",
        type : "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
           if(result.results.length){
            lat=result.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            lng=result.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

           //map
           var map     
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);     
            var mapOptions = {
              zoom: 15,
              center: latlng,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas1'), mapOptions);
          ............
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes size:

google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
```