# How to display map in hidden area (just insert code in right place)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, maps, hidden

I've seen solutions to show map in hidden div but I dont know how to fix, it's not clear where to insert the code (I'm a desiger, not programmer). This is the issue: [Click here to see the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782632/google-map-display-from-a-hidden-area). It says to put `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')` somewhere in the code to get the map working in hidden areas.

So where do I put this in my code? Does anybody can help me please?
I tried to put when select Layer 2 but dont even show the input field.

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/4y42005t/

(is not working in jsfiddle because of jquery.geocomplete.js)

Comment: The problem is you have not initialize your map. Seems like you are using [jQuery Geocoding and Places Autocomplete Plugin](http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/), so the best thing to do would be to read their site and tutorials.

Comment: Hi @kaho, sorry I forgot to put that part of the code :) but yes I had initialized and nothing happen. I read that docs but didnt find anything useful, could you please give me a light? tks

Comment: would it be because you didn't set the style on your `map_canvas` to something like this: `style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);"`?

Comment: @kaho , is not this... Is about "google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')" , but I do know where to put into my code

Comment: I finally figured it out :) sorry for the misunderstanding at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

You actually have to do it after you do `$('#layer2').show();` so that `map_canvas` would update its value from `x: 0,y: 0,w: 0,h: 0` to `x: 71,y: 8,w: 600,h: 400`.

Then you can trigger the resize method `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');`

I made a [jsfiddle live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/14v4yvtt/2/).